# Convert an array into an index hash in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, set

I have an array, and I want to make a hash so I can quickly ask "is X in the array?".

In perl, there is an easy (and fast) way to do this:

```
my @array = qw( 1 2 3 );
my %hash;
@hash{@array} = undef;
```

This generates a hash that looks like:

```
{
    1 => undef,
    2 => undef,
    3 => undef,
}
```

The best I've come up with in Ruby is:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
hash = Hash[array.map {|x| [x, nil]}]
```

which gives:

```
{1=>nil, 2=>nil, 3=>nil}
```

Is there a better Ruby way?

### EDIT 1

No, Array.include? is not a good idea. Its **slow**. It does a query in O(n) instead of O(1). My example array had three elements for brevity; assume the actual one has a million elements. Let's do a little benchmarking:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require 'benchmark'

array = (1..1_000_000).to_a
hash = Hash[array.map {|x| [x, nil]}]

Benchmark.bm(15) do |x|
    x.report("Array.include?") { 1000.times { array.include?(500_000) } }
    x.report("Hash.include?") { 1000.times { hash.include?(500_000) } }
end
```

Produces:

```
                     user     system      total        real
Array.include?  46.190000   0.160000  46.350000 ( 46.593477)
Hash.include?    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000523)
```

Comment: Don't forget to consider the time it takes to do the conversion.  Of course, if your situation allows, using a set to begin with (as suggested by @Zach Langley) obviates this cost.

Comment: To be fair the benchmark above should include converting from an array to a hash

Comment: @drhenner in theory, sure. In practice, not really—it's basically irrelevant. The conversion is done once, the lookup many, many, many times. I forget what I was working on when I asked this, but in the actual program the lookup was probably done many millions of times, after converting once.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If all you need the hash for is membership, consider using a [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html):

> ## Set
>
> [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) implements a collection of unordered values with no
>   duplicates. This is a hybrid of Array's intuitive inter-operation
>   facilities and Hash's fast lookup.
>
> [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) is easy to use with [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) objects (implementing
>   `each`). Most of the initializer methods and binary operators accept
>   generic [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) objects besides sets and arrays. An
>   [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) object can be converted to [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) using the
>   [`to_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_set) method.
>
> [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) uses Hash as storage, so you must note the following points:
>
> - Equality of elements is determined according to `Object#eql?` and `Object#hash`.
> - Set assumes that the identity of each element does not change while it is stored. Modifying an element of a set will render the set to an
>     unreliable state.
> - When a string is to be stored, a frozen copy of the string is stored instead unless the original string is already frozen.
>
> ### Comparison
>
> The comparison operators `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=` are implemented as
>   shorthand for the {proper_,}{subset?,superset?} methods. However, the
>   `<=>` operator is intentionally left out because not every pair of
>   sets is comparable. ({x,y} vs. {x,z} for example)
>
> ### Example
>
> ```
> require 'set'
> s1 = Set.new [1, 2]                   # -> #<Set: {1, 2}>
> s2 = [1, 2].to_set                    # -> #<Set: {1, 2}>
> s1 == s2                              # -> true
> s1.add("foo")                         # -> #<Set: {1, 2, "foo"}>
> s1.merge([2, 6])                      # -> #<Set: {1, 2, "foo", 6}>
> s1.subset? s2                         # -> false
> s2.subset? s1                         # -> true
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ### Public Class Methods
>
> #### new(enum = nil)
>
> Creates a new set containing the elements of the given enumerable
>   object.
>
> If a block is given, the elements of enum are preprocessed by the
>   given block.

Answer (score 25):

try this one:

```
a=[1,2,3]
Hash[a.zip]
```

Comment: Perfect! Most elegant way.

Comment: `Hash[a.zip]` also returns the same response.

Comment: "this certainly works... but i don't think it's the most efficient... you're iterating twice in this case. Not a concern of course with an array of length 2, but still worth noting." @brad from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9434078/380607

Answer (score 14):

You can do this very handy trick:

```
Hash[*[1, 2, 3, 4].map {|k| [k, nil]}.flatten]
=> {1=>nil, 2=>nil, 3=>nil, 4=>nil}
```

Comment: This worked great for me. I changed it to be [k,k] instead of [k, nil]. Thanks for this post

Comment: Why not just do ```Hash[ [1, 2, 3, 4].map {|k| [k, nil]} ]``` ? There's no need for the extra splat and flatten.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to quickly ask "is X in the array?" you should use [`Array#include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002226).

**Edit (in response to addition in OP):**

If you want speedy look up times, use a Set. Having a Hash that points to all `nil`s is silly. Conversion is an easy process too with `Array#to_set`.

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'

array = (1..1_000_000).to_a
set = array.to_set

Benchmark.bm(15) do |x|
    x.report("Array.include?") { 1000.times { array.include?(500_000) } }
    x.report("Set.include?") { 1000.times { set.include?(500_000) } }
end
```

Results on my machine:

```
                     user     system      total        real
Array.include?  36.200000   0.140000  36.340000 ( 36.740605)
Set.include?     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000515)
```

You should consider just using a set to begin with, instead of an array so that a conversion is never necessary.

Comment: Please see my (newly added) section on why not Array#include? in the question.

Answer (score 6):

I'm fairly certain that there isn't a one-shot clever way to construct this hash. My inclination would be to just be explicit and state what I'm doing:

```
hash = {}
array.each{|x| hash[x] = nil}
```

It doesn't look particularly elegant, but it's clear, and does the job.

FWIW, your original suggestion (under Ruby 1.8.6 at least) doesn't seem to work. I get an "ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash" error. Hash.[] expects a literal, even-lengthed list of values:

```
Hash[a, 1, b, 2] # => {a => 1, b => 2}
```

so I tried changing your code to:

```
hash = Hash[*array.map {|x| [x, nil]}.flatten]
```

but the performance is dire:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require 'benchmark'

array = (1..100_000).to_a

Benchmark.bm(15) do |x|
  x.report("assignment loop") {hash = {}; array.each{|e| hash[e] = nil}}
  x.report("hash constructor") {hash = Hash[*array.map {|e| [e, nil]}.flatten]}
end
```

gives

```
                     user     system      total        real
assignment loop  0.440000   0.200000   0.640000 (  0.657287)
hash constructor  4.440000   0.250000   4.690000 (  4.758663)
```

Unless I'm missing something here, a simple assignment loop seems the clearest and most efficient way to construct this hash.

Comment: I realized I left off the closing ] in the code... Fixed. It works with ruby 1.8.7 here, and also 1.9.0

Comment: For Ruby 1.8.6, you need the splat, i.e., hash = Hash[*array.map { |x| [x, nil] }.flatten]

Answer (score 5):

Rampion beat me to it. Set might be the answer.

You can do:

```
require 'set'
set = array.to_set
set.include?(x)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your way of creating the hash looks good. I had a muck around in irb and this is another way

```
>> [1,2,3,4].inject(Hash.new) { |h,i| {i => nil}.merge(h) }
=> {1=>nil, 2=>nil, 3=>nil, 4=>nil}
```

Comment: Neat approach, but obscenely slow; on 1..1_000_000: 1.4s (my map code) vs. got-bored-waiting after 3 minutes.

Comment: Empirically, that seems to run in O(n^2)

Comment: heheh. I didn't say it was fast!
You can always make a to_h method for class Array using your Hash[map] way.

Comment: Use merge! should be much faster

Comment: array.inject(Hash.new) { |h,i| h.merge!({i => nil}) } turns out to be pretty fast but still `array.each{|e| hash[e] = nil}` is 3.5 times faster

Answer (score 2):

I think [chrismear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410623/convert-an-array-into-an-index-hash-in-ruby#411031)'s point on using assignment over creation is great.  To make the whole thing a little more Ruby-esque, though, I might suggest assigning something *other* than `nil` to each element:

```
hash = {}
array.each { |x| hash[x] = 1 } # or true or something else "truthy"
...
if hash[376]                   # instead of if hash.has_key?(376)
  ...
end
```

The problem with assigning to `nil` is that you have to use `has_key?` instead of `[]`, since `[]` give you `nil` (your marker value) if the `Hash` doesn't have the specified key.  You *could* get around this by using a different default value, but why go through the extra work?

```
# much less elegant than above:
hash = Hash.new(42)
array.each { |x| hash[x] = nil }
...
unless hash[376]
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the goal here; If you wanted to know if X was in the array, why not do array.include?("X") ?

Comment: Please see my (newly added) section on why not Array#include? in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Doing some benchmarking on the suggestions so far gives that chrismear and Gaius's assignment-based hash creation is slightly faster than my map method (and assigning nil is slightly faster than assigning true). mtyaka and rampion's Set suggestion is about 35% slower to create.

As far as lookups, `hash.include?(x)` is a very tiny amount faster than `hash[x]`; both are twice as a fast as `set.include?(x)`.

```
                user     system      total        real
chrismear   6.050000   0.850000   6.900000 (  6.959355)
derobert    6.010000   1.060000   7.070000 (  7.113237)
Gaius       6.210000   0.810000   7.020000 (  7.049815)
mtyaka      8.750000   1.190000   9.940000 (  9.967548)
rampion     8.700000   1.210000   9.910000 (  9.962281)

                user     system      total        real
times      10.880000   0.000000  10.880000 ( 10.921315)
set        93.030000  17.490000 110.520000 (110.817044)
hash-i     45.820000   8.040000  53.860000 ( 53.981141)
hash-e     47.070000   8.280000  55.350000 ( 55.487760)
```

Benchmarking code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'

array = (1..5_000_000).to_a

Benchmark.bmbm(10) do |bm|
    bm.report('chrismear') { hash = {}; array.each{|x| hash[x] = nil} }
    bm.report('derobert')  { hash = Hash[array.map {|x| [x, nil]}] }
    bm.report('Gaius')     { hash = {}; array.each{|x| hash[x] = true} }
    bm.report('mtyaka')    { set = array.to_set }
    bm.report('rampion')   { set = Set.new(array) }
end

hash = Hash[array.map {|x| [x, true]}]
set = array.to_set
array = nil
GC.start

GC.disable
Benchmark.bmbm(10) do |bm|
    bm.report('times')  { 100_000_000.times { } }
    bm.report('set')    { 100_000_000.times { set.include?(500_000) } }
    bm.report('hash-i') { 100_000_000.times { hash.include?(500_000) } }
    bm.report('hash-e') { 100_000_000.times { hash[500_000] } }
end
GC.enable
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not bothered what the hash values are

```
irb(main):031:0> a=(1..1_000_000).to_a ; a.length
=> 1000000
irb(main):032:0> h=Hash[a.zip a] ; h.keys.length
=> 1000000
```

Takes a second or so on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an equivalent of this Perl code:

```
grep {$_ eq $element} @array
```

You can just use the simple Ruby code:

```
array.include?(element)
```

Comment: Please see my (newly added) section on why not Array#include? in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat way to cache lookups with a Hash:

```
a = (1..1000000).to_a
h = Hash.new{|hash,key| hash[key] = true if a.include? key}
```

Pretty much what it does is create a default constructor for new hash values, then stores "true" in the cache if it's in the array (nil otherwise). This allows lazy loading into the cache, just in case you don't use every element.

Comment: The hash load is so quick, this would hardly ever make sense, unless you're really short on memory. The entire Hash load is O(n), a single a.include? call is also O(n).

Comment: In this case, yes, but this can be generalized to memoize any function of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

This preserves 0's if your hash was `[0,0,0,1,0]`

```
  hash = {}
  arr.each_with_index{|el, idx| hash.merge!({(idx + 1 )=> el }) }
```

Returns :

```
  # {1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>1, 5=>0}
```