# Ruby array to hash: each element the key and derive value from it

Tags: ruby

I have an array of strings, and want to make a hash out of it. Each element of the array will be the key, and I want to make the value being computed from that key. Is there a Ruby way of doing this?

For example:

`['a','b']` to convert to `{'a'=>'A','b'=>'B'}`

Comment: Are strings unique? What if they are not? Do you want an exception?

Comment: yes they will be unique. If they are not I would do a uniq before that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ruby's [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) method is a neat way of doing what you want

```
['a', 'b'].each_with_object({}) { |k, h| h[k] = k.upcase }
```

Answer (score 56):

You can:

```
a = ['a', 'b']
Hash[a.map {|v| [v,v.upcase]}]
```

Comment: this certainly works... but i don't think it's the *most* efficient... you're iterating twice in this case.  Not a concern of course with an array of length 2, but still worth noting.

Answer (score 22):

```
%w{a b c}.reduce({}){|a,v| a[v] = v.upcase; a}
```

Comment: I like your solution! Very slick!

Answer (score 7):

From Rails 6.x, you can use [`Enumerable#index_with`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_with):

```
irb(main):002:0> ['a', 'b'].index_with { |s| s.upcase }
=> {"a"=>"A", "b"=>"B"}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way:

```
a.zip(a.map(&:upcase)).to_h

#=>{"a"=>"A", "b"=>"B"}
```

Answer (score 5):

Which ever way you look at it you will need to iterate the initial array. Here's another way :

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
h = Hash[a.collect {|v| [v, v.upcase]}]
#=> {"a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "c"=>"C"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a naive and simple solution that converts the current character to a symbol to be used as the key. And just for fun it capitalizes the value. :)

```
h = Hash.new
['a', 'b'].each {|a| h[a.to_sym] = a.upcase}
puts h

# => {:a=>"A", :b=>"B"}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Pass a block to `.to_h`

```rb
[ 'a', 'b' ].to_h{ |element| [ element, element.upcase ] }
#=> {"a"=>"A", "b"=>"B"}
```

*Thanks to @SMAG for the refactor suggestion!*

Comment: [you can just pass the block directly to `to_h`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array:to_h)
[ 'a', 'b' ].to_h { |element| [ element, element.upcase ] }

Comment: @SMAG Oh damn, that's slick. Did they recently add this, or do you know which version of Ruby it was added in?

Comment: looks like it was added some time between 2.3 and 2.7, from the link I provided, but not sure how to get any more specific than that.

Comment: @SMAG That's good enough. Looks like it's been around quite a while and people can refer to your comment for a rough idea of minimum version requirement. Thanks for looking into.a

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the real Ruby way but should be close enough:

```
hash = {}
['a', 'b'].each do |x|
  hash[x] = x.upcase
end

p hash  # prints {"a"=>"A", "b"=>"B"}
```

As a function we would have this:

```
def theFunk(array)
  hash = {}
  array.each do |x|
    hash[x] = x.upcase
  end
  hash
end


p theFunk ['a', 'b', 'c']  # prints {"a"=>"A", "b"=>"B", "c"=>"C"}
```